# How to put a tkinter application on hold while the user pick values on an interactive plot embedded in the app

Tags: python, multithreading, matplotlib, tkinter, interactive

I am trying to build a tkinter application to process data and at some point in the process, the user must pick values on an interactive figure. I made this work pretty well but I encounter an issue.

Basically, I have a button in my app which launches the process. When it is time, I create a TopLevel widget in which an interactive plot is embedded and the user can pick a value appearing on the graph with a click. However, the process doesn't pause even if the user haven't picked a value yet. So what I would like is to put the process on hold until the user picks a value.

As you may have noticed from the tags, I tried to do it with threading but it didn't work. As I never tried to use threads before, it is very likely that I did something wrong.

Here is a piece of the code I wrote sor far and what I tried with the threading module:

- this class that handle the TopLevel window and the interactive plot (I omitted the methods not related to my issue):

```
    def __init__(self, parameters, main_menu):

        # We use this attributes for the TopLevel widget
        self.main_menu = main_menu
        self.gui = self.main_menu.gui

        self.color_font = main_menu.color_font
        self.background_color = main_menu.background_color
        self.button_font = main_menu.button_font

        # Proper data related attributes
        super().__init__(parameters)
        self.worksheet = None
        self.pressure = []
        self.V60 = []
        self.corrected_volume = []
        self.membrane_pressure = []
        self.corrected_pressure = []

        self.figure = None
        self.ax = None

        self.P1 = DoubleVar(value=0)
        self.P2 = DoubleVar(value=0)
        self.V1 = DoubleVar(value=0)
        self.V2 = DoubleVar(value=0)

        self.filename = self.parameters["Corrected data filename"].get()
        self.new_filename = self.filename

        # We use this attributes for the TopLevel widget used for the choice of (P1,V1) and (P2,V2)
        self.selection_window = None
        self.selection_window_width = 1080
        self.selection_window_height = 720

        self.frame = None
        self.canvas = None

        self.toolbar = None

        self.index1 = [0]
        self.index2 = [0]
        self.artist = None

        self.clicked1 = 0
        self.clicked2 = 0

        self.choice_over = BooleanVar(value=False)
        self.result = threading.Event()

    def animate(self, i):
        if self.artist is None and self.clicked1 > 0:
            self.artist = self.ax.scatter(self.P1.get(), self.V1.get(), color='r', s=100)

    def on_pick(self, event):
        self.index1 = event.ind
        self.P1.set(value=self.corrected_pressure[self.index1[0]])
        self.V1.set(value=self.corrected_volume[self.index1[0]])
        if self.artist is not None:
            self.artist.remove()
            self.artist = None
        self.clicked1 += 1

    def display_selection_window(self):

        try:
            self.selection_window = Toplevel(self.gui.root, bg=self.background_color)
            self.selection_window.withdraw()
            self.selection_window.iconbitmap('assets/Logo.ico')
            self.selection_window.geometry(f'{self.selection_window_width}x{self.selection_window_height}'
                                           f'+{int((self.selection_window.winfo_screenwidth() - self.selection_window_width) / 2)}'
                                           f'+{- 50 + int((self.selection_window.winfo_screenheight() - self.selection_window_height) / 2)}')
            self.selection_window.resizable(width=False, height=False)

            self.frame = Frame(self.selection_window, bg=self.background_color)

            self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.figure, master=self.frame)
            self.figure.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', self.on_pick)
            self.toolbar = CustomToolbar(self.canvas, self.frame)
            self.toolbar.config(background=self.background_color)
            self.toolbar.update()

            self.confirmation_button = Button(self.selection_window, text="confirm",
                                              command=lambda: [self.selection_window.destroy(), self.result.set()])

            self.frame.pack()
            self.canvas.draw()
            self.canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH)
            self.toolbar.pack(fill=X)
            self.confirmation_button.pack()
            self.selection_window.deiconify()

            ani = FuncAnimation(self.figure, lambda i: self.animate(i), interval=100, cache_frame_data=False)
            
            
        except:
            Log().write_log_exception()
```

- Here is the function in which I call the thread:

```
    def complete_data_process(self):

        progress_bar_canvas = 0

        try:

            assert os.path.exists(self.gui.parameters["Data path"].get())

            number_of_tasks = 4

            progress_bar_canvas = Canvas(self.gui.root, width=400, height=20, bd=0, highlightthickness=0)
            progress_bar_canvas.create_rectangle(0, 0, progress_bar_canvas.cget("width"),
                                                 progress_bar_canvas.cget("height"), fill="", width=3)

            progress_bar_canvas.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.9, anchor=CENTER)

            self.tube_calibration.load_data()
            self.tube_calibration.save_figure()

            self.update_progress_bar(progress_bar_canvas, 1, number_of_tasks)

            self.air_calibration.load_data()
            self.air_calibration.save_figure()

            self.update_progress_bar(progress_bar_canvas, 2, number_of_tasks)

            self.corrected_data.load_data()
            self.corrected_data.save_figure(coefficient=self.tube_calibration.line_equation[0],
                                            interpolator=self.air_calibration.interpolator)

            self.update_progress_bar(progress_bar_canvas, 3, number_of_tasks)

            thread = threading.Thread(target=self.corrected_data.display_selection_window)
            thread.start()

            self.corrected_data.result.wait()
            
            self.update_progress_bar(progress_bar_canvas, 4, number_of_tasks)

            progress_bar_canvas.place_forget()

            answer = messagebox.askquestion('Succès',
                                            "Le traitement complet des données a été effectué avec succès.\n"
                                            f"Les graphes ont été sauvegardés dans {self.tube_calibration.user_dir}"
                                            f"\\{self.tube_calibration.dir}.\n\nVoulez-vous ouvrir le dossier?")

            if answer == "yes":
                os.startfile(f"{self.tube_calibration.user_dir}/{self.tube_calibration.dir}/")
```

I also tried this

```
while not self.choice_over.get():
    ani = FuncAnimation(self.figure, lambda i: self.animate(i), interval=100, cache_frame_data=False)
```

but it didn't work.

So if you come up with a solution, even if it doesn't use threading (which honestly would be so much easier), I thank you in advance.

Sorry if my English is sometimes inacurrate and sorry for the long post.

Thanks for your time,

Paul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tkinter has features specifically for this situation. `wait_window` will wait until a window has been destroyed. You can also wait for a variable to be set with `wait_variable`.

It's too much work to get your code working, but here's a really simple example to illustrate the point. Click "Click me" and you'll see a dialog that lets you pick a color. When you click on a color, it sets a variable. The `show` method will wait for the variable to be set before returning.

```
import tkinter as tk

class CustomDialog(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.color_var = tk.StringVar()
        self.withdraw()
        self.label = tk.Label(self, text="Choose a color")
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self, background="bisque", width=200, height=200)
        self.label.pack(side="top")
        self.canvas.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

        x = 5
        y = 10
        for color in ("red", "yellow", "orange", "green", "blue"):
            self.canvas.create_rectangle(x, y, x+40, y+40, fill=color, outline="")
            x += 40

        self.canvas.bind("<1>", self.set_color)

    def show(self):
        self.deiconify()
        self.wait_variable(self.color_var)
        return self.color_var.get()

    def set_color(self, event):
        item = self.canvas.find_closest(event.x, event.y)
        self.color_var.set(self.canvas.itemcget(item[0], "fill"))
        self.withdraw()

def do_something():
    dialog = CustomDialog()
    color = dialog.show()
    root.configure(background=color)
    dialog.destroy()

root = tk.Tk()
button = tk.Button(root, text="Click me", command=do_something)
button.pack(padx=20, pady=20)

root.mainloop()
```